# Where to ask a question about online stores and which is better while buying a laptop?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I want to ask about online stores such as Amazon, Newegg, erc. and I don't know on which Stack Exchange website I should ask such questions.

I need to ask about buying a laptop and which website will be better and some other questions.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Shopping questions are off-topic on all Stack Exchange sites. The SE chat sites, however, were designed to allow a broader range of questions—you may want to visit [the Super User chat](http://chat.superuser.com) which would be the most appropriate location.

Answer (score 1):

If you're asking about using the API of a store, you can ask [Stack Overflow.](https://stackoverflow.com/) Have a first go attempt at the ready in the question and not just a "how do I go do this what?"

If you want to ask about shopping, you can ask people at forums, chat, read spiked reviews or anywhere that isn't Stack Exchange. [It's off topic](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/11/qa-is-hard-lets-go-shopping/).

If it's a well-crafted question which eventually would lead you toward bettering your skills in knowing how to shop, such as knowing what [matrix type a monitor is](https://superuser.com/questions/185284/how-can-i-know-the-matrix-type-of-monitor), that would have a chance on Super User.