# Where to ask buying questions about peripherals?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

Is it even OK to ask such questions? If it is, should I ask these on [Super User](http://superuser.com) or somewhere else?

For example I need a suggestion about good sound speakers that have quite long cables (for some specific reasons)?

Comment: Even I want to know where to ask such questions. +1 :)

Comment: If you want long cables, then just buy an extension lead.

Answer (score 1):

I think that kind of questions would be opinion-based which is not allowed on SO and are considered off-topic.

See these similar questions:

[Where to ask a question about online stores and which is better while buying a laptop?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86876/where-to-ask-a-question-about-online-stores-and-which-is-better-while-buying-a-l?rq=1)

[Where do I ask questions about product benchmarks and comparisons?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191167/where-do-i-ask-questions-about-product-benchmarks-and-comparisons?rq=1)